# Building TensorFlow 2 with bazel 0.29.1 on Windows 10 fails

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow2.0

Trying to compile **TF 2.0 with Bazel**, ends up in a failure.
I am struggling this issue for quite a while, looked it up online, but haven't found any solution to the exact problem. Several running configuration (with or w/o Cuda, with or w/o creating zip file, etc) eventually leading to the same failure.

System information:

- OS Platform and Distribution (Windows 10)
- TensorFlow installed from (source)
- TensorFlow version: 2.0 (master branch on 07 Nov 2019, to be exact)
- Python version: 3.7
- Installed using virtualenv? pip? conda?: No
- Bazel version (if compiling from source): 0.29.1
- GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source): 8.1.0
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 10.0/7
- GPU model and memory: GeForce GTX 1050 15.88 GB RAM

My actions:

```
1. git checkout master (in the TF git repo)
2. bazel clean
3. configure (all defaults except for python path and Cuda)
4. bazel build --config=cuda --define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true tensorflow:tensorflow_cc.dll
```

Failure message:

> ERROR: C:/users/shahar/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2537:1:
>   Executing genrule //tensorflow/core:version_info_gen failed (Exit 5)
>   LAUNCHER ERROR: Cannot launch process: "C:/Program
>   Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/python.exe"
>   C:\users\shahar_bazel_shahar\duchsbgv\execroot\org_tensorflow\bazel-out\x64_windows-opt\bin\tensorflow\tools\git\gen_git_source.zip
>   --generate external/local_config_git/gen/spec.json external/local_config_git/gen/head
>   external/local_config_git/gen/branch_ref
>   bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/util/version_info.cc
>   --git_tag_override= Reason: (error: 5): Access is denied.

What am i doing wrong?

Edit:
added a junction with @László advice:

```
mklink /j c:\python "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"
```

and used it when **"configure"** asked me to, for both python.exe and the libs, yet the error remains. details:

> ERROR: C:/users/shahar/git/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2537:1:
>   Executing genrule //tensorflow/core:version_info_gen failed (Exit 5)
>   LAUNCHER ERROR: Cannot launch process: "C:/python/python.exe"
>   C:\users\shahar_bazel_shahar\duchsbgv\execroot\org_tensorflow\bazel-out\x64_windows-opt\bin\tensorflow\tools\git\gen_git_source.zip
>   --generate external/local_config_git/gen/spec.json external/local_config_git/gen/head
>   external/local_config_git/gen/branch_ref
>   bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/util/version_info.cc
>   --git_tag_override= Reason: (error: 5): Access is denied.

Edit_2:
Again with @László help:
I ran:

```
bazel info execution_root
```

got a path, cd into it.
From there i ran:

```
c:\python\python.exe c:\users\shahar\_bazel_shahar\duchsbgv\execroot\org_tensorflow\bazel-out\x64_windows-opt\bin\tensorflow\tools\git\gen_git_source.zip --generate external/local_config_git/gen/spec.json external/local_config_git/gen/head external/local_config_git/gen/branch_ref c:\tmp\foo.cc --git_tag_override=
```

and got the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "\?\C:\Users\Shahar\AppData\Local\Temp\Bazel.runfiles_ltu2ig_a\runfiles\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\tools\git\gen_git_source.py",
>   line 340, in 
>       generate(args.generate, args.git_tag_override)   File "\?\C:\Users\Shahar\AppData\Local\Temp\Bazel.runfiles_ltu2ig_a\runfiles\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\tools\git\gen_git_source.py",
>   line 273, in generate
>       write_version_info(dest_file, git_version)   File "\?\C:\Users\Shahar\AppData\Local\Temp\Bazel.runfiles_ltu2ig_a\runfiles\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\tools\git\gen_git_source.py",
>   line 228, in write_version_info
>       open(filename, "w").write(contents) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\tmp\foo.cc'

Comment: Re: update: run `bazel info execution_root` -- it prints a directory. Then `cd` into that, and try running `c:\python\python.exe c:\users\shahar_bazel_shahar\duchsbgv\execroot\org_tensorflow\bazel-out\x64_windows-opt\bin\tensorflow\tools\git\gen_git_source.zip --generate external/local_config_git/gen/spec.json external/local_config_git/gen/head external/local_config_git/gen/branch_ref c:\tmp\foo.cc --git_tag_override=`. Does it generate `c:\tmp\foo.cc`?

Comment: @László, Did that, didn't work. If i run it as is, the path "c:\users\shahar_bazel_shahar" leads to a failure since it is missing a backslash - "c:\users\shahar\_bazel_shahar". Fixing this still fails, with a "FileNotFoundError". I Edited the post with details.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the space in the Python path.

Try this:

1. open cmd.exe
2. create a junction `c:\python` pointing to the real Python directory:

   ```
   mklink /j c:\python "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"
   ```

   You can use any other path than `c:\python`, just make sure there's no space or special characters in it.
3. run `./configure.py` again, use `c:\python`

Comment: Just did that. Ran for a while and then **failed again**. same Error type, message almost indetical. I edited the original post with detailes